# How do you find the lowest key in a maximum sum path of a binary search tree in O(n)?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am already calculating the maximum path sum, but i want to figure out which is the lowest key inside the path. How should i get this information? I am having troubles because if i check for the minimum inside the maximum path sum, i dont get what i am looking for (ofcourse) because im recurring firstly to the lowest element inside the BST.
Below what i tried:

```
int Max_Path_Sum(struct node* root){
    int res= INT_MIN;   
    int min = INT_MAX;
    Max_Path_Sum_Util( root, &res, &min);
    printf("%d\n\n%d", min,res);    
    return res;
}


int Max_Path_Sum_Util(struct node* root, int *res, int *min){
    if(root == NULL) return  0;
    if( root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)return root->key;

    int ls = Max_Path_Sum_Util(root->left ,res , min);
    int rs = Max_Path_Sum_Util(root->right ,res , min);

    if(root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL){
        *res = max(*res , ls + rs + root->key);
        return max(ls,rs)+ root->key;
    }   
    int sum = (root->left == NULL) ? rs+root->key : ls+root->key;
    if(root != NULL && *min> root->key)*min = root->key;
    return sum;
}
```

I am recieving the lowest key inside of the BST but i understand why it isnt the real result, beside some rare cases. My BST isnt balanced(its just an homework) So insterting keys without caring about balance.

```
struct node *root=New_Node(4);
Insert(root, 2);  
Insert(root, 1);  
Insert(root, 3);  
Insert(root, 6);  
Insert(root, 5); 
Insert(root, 4);
Insert(root, -5);
Insert(root,0);
Insert( root, 3);
Insert(root, 2);
```

Using this tree the result of maximum path sum is 24, which should be correct.
As minimum i recieve 6, which isnt the right answer. I think it should be 2.

Comment: There appears to be several cases where you don't test/set `*min` for the current node (e.g. for a leaf).

Comment: Yes, i know that, but i dont know how to do the proper check

Comment: Your comment about negative keys is unclear and / or possibly mistaken.  Do you mean that your tree can be relied upon to not contain negative keys?  For it is *not* the case that a path that passes through a node with a negative key cannot nevertheless have the maximum sum.

Comment: Also, your implementation appears to be computing the maximum path sum for paths *from the root node to a leaf*, as opposed to for general paths inside the tree (a harder problem) or paths starting at the root but not necessarily going all the way to a leaf.  That's fine, but please confirm that it's what you actually want.

Comment: my bad about negatives.  Thats missleading and i will edit. The actual algorithm should not be from root to node, atleast from the results im getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am having troubles because if i check for the minimum inside the
>   maximum path sum, i dont get what i am looking for (ofcourse) because
>   im recurring firstly to the lowest element inside the BST.

I'd characterize the issue differently: you cannot directly record the minimum node along the path, because you don't know during any particular execution of the recursive function whether it is operating on a node that will turn out to be on the maximum path.  But this genuine issue presents an actual problem only for some implementations.

When searching for a path in a tree via an algorithm that works one node at a time, you generally have two cases to consider as you process each node:

- the path of interest passes through the current node, or
- it doesn't

Specific algorithms generally subdivide those further.  In particular, your recursive approach that processes the tree from the chosen root node toward the leaf nodes has these more specific cases to account for:

- the path passes through the current node from its parent node (either ending at this node or continuing through exactly one of its children)
- the path passes through this node and *does not* contain its parent node (it may also pass through one or both of its children)
- the path does not pass through this node, but it is contained in the subtree rooted at this node
- the path does not pass through any node in the subtree rooted at the current node

When processing a given node during your recursive traversal, you need to provide an answer as if that node were the root of the tree (because it might be), and also sufficient information for the answer to be determined correctly if it isn't.

Now note that neither the maximum path sum in a tree **T<sub>1</sub>** nor the minimum element along that maximum path directly informs computation of those properties for a larger tree **T<sub>2</sub>** that contains **T<sub>1</sub>** as a subtree.  You can't just add maximum path sums from a node's left and right subtrees -- that gives the right answer only in the case that in each subtree, the maximum path starts at the subtree root, so that you can join them together through their common parent to form a path.  If the maximum path in one of the subtrees does not contain the subtree root or the subtree root is somewhere in the middle of the maximum path, then you can't form a path by joining the parent node to it.

Thus you need separate sets of information about each subtree:

- information about the general maximum-sum path within that subtree, and
- information about the maximum-sum path within it that starts at the subtree root (even if, as will be common, its path sum is less than the maximum in the subtree)

When processing a node, you can combine the latter sets of information about the subtrees rooted at its children to compute *both* sets of information for node under consideration.  Moreover, you need to maintain data separation so that information applying to one of a node's child trees is not lost when you process the other.  So what does that look like?

Let's first introduce another data structure to make it easier to keep track:

```
struct path_info {
    int sum;
    int min_value;
};
```

Now let's consider what your recursive function's signature needs to look like.  There are several ways it could be done, but I'm going to suggest this:

```
struct path_info compute_max_path(struct node *root, struct path_info *max_leg)
```

The return value conveys the result for the tree rooted at the specified node, and the information needed to build such a result for a larger tree is conveyed via the `max_leg` output parameter.

I don't intend to write a complete solution for you, but I suspect there is one more idea that you're missing: how to segregate `max_leg` results for the subtrees.  The key here is that when you recurse, you do not forward the `max_leg` parameter to the recursive calls.  Instead, you declare new objects, and pass pointers to those:

```
struct path_info left_leg;
struct path_info left_result = compute_max_path(root->left, &left_leg);
struct path_info right_leg;
struct path_info right result = compute_max_path(root->right, &right_leg);
```

You then have all the information you need to set the `max_leg` data for the current node and to compute and return the maximum path information for its subtree.